# Efficient way of getting meta values in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, custom-post-type

What is the efficient way of getting meta values of a custom post type in wordpress?
So far there are two ways I know.

1. First is to create a custom query like:

   ```
   SELECT ... (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = wp.ID and meta_key
   = 'fname') as fname .. FROM wp_posts wp INNER JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON pm.post_id
   = wp.id WHERE post_type = 'customer'
   ```
2. Use `get_post_meta`.

   ```
   $meta_values = get_post_meta($post_id)
   ```

   then use a foreach loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All WordPress *post meta data* is internally cached, running your own SQL query will not have this benefit (unless you implement your own caching).

The function [`get_post_meta()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.2/src/wp-includes/post.php#L1757) calls [`get_metadata()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.2/src/wp-includes/meta.php#L256), which in turn calls [`wp_cache_get()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.2/src/wp-includes/cache.php#L96). And from that point on, where it goes inside the class `WP_Object_Cache`, I got lost...

Anyway, I've read from multiple sources ([WordPress Development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/), [WP Forums](http://wordpress.org/support/), [wp-hackers](http://wordpress-hackers.1065353.n5.nabble.com/) mailing list) that using `get_post_meta` is the way to go.

Comment: Hi there, can you also advice, what's better? get_post_meta for all meta keys at once and then iterate through them, or get_post_meta individually on the needed key?